# Running a macro on cells that I have selected

Tags: excel, vba, cell, selected

I need to create a Macro that only works on cells that I have selected.

I need to execute the below code for only cells that I have selected and not a range since the formatting will change frequently.
Below is my code:

```
    Range("B2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=XLOOKUP(RC[9],'[Region Name and Numbers.xlsx]Region Store'!C2,'[Region Name and Numbers.xlsx]Region Store'!C1,0,0)"
    Range("B2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:B991")
    Range("B2:B991").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("B2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=0
    Range("B2").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Please share what exactly you will be selecting. A single-column range in column `B`, non-contiguous cells in column `B`, or something else? BTW, you cannot mix R1C1-style references (`RC[9]`) and A1-style references (`C2`).

Comment: It looks like you've used the macro recorder, typed a formula in B2, and copied it down to B991. Try this instead: use the macro recorder, select B2:B991, type in the formula you want for B2, then press Ctrl + Enter.

Comment: Is there a way to make the Macro run by selecting different cells each time?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
Sub Test()

    With Selection
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=XLOOKUP(RC[9],'Sheet2'!C2,'Sheet2'!C1,0,0)"
        
        'You can't copy paste to non-continous ranges, so look at each area.
        Dim Area As Range
        For Each Area In .Areas
            Area.Copy
            Area.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Next Area
    End With
    
End Sub
```